# Remove folder name and redirect url

Tags: nginx

Im trying to write a nginx rule to make `www.domain.com/media/*` redirect to `media.domain.com/*`

I have tried like this:

```
location /media {
  rewrite ^ $scheme://media.domain.com$request_uri redirect;
}
```

But it redirect to `media.domain.com/media/` How can I remove the last /media/ folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one should work:

```
location /media/ {
    rewrite ^/media/(.*)$ $scheme://media.domain.com/$1 redirect;
}
```

Reference:

- http://nginx.org/r/rewrite
- `man pcresyntax`
- `man pcrepattern`

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
location /media {
  rewrite ^media/(.*) $scheme://media.domain.com/$1 redirect;
}
```

There are several examples in the documentation: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule